# JQuery ломает CSS стили

Tags: html, css, jquery, django

Есть проблема с тем, что **при подключении файлов JQuery в мой Django проект ломаются все стили на странице, к которой подключаются,** до подключения всё работает корректно. *Я новичок и скорее всего просто чего-то не понимаю*, сразу скажу что знаю про `collectstatic` и все те вещи которые нужно делать со статическими файлами, ибо стили работают нормально *до подключения скрипта* и в файле `settings.py` все пути указаны верно.

> JQuery

*код скрипта довольно простой и служит по большей части чисто для адаптивного меню, и скрытия некоторых тегов `html` по нажатию.*

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Менюшка и появляющиеся категории
        $('.nav_show_btn').click(function() {
            let display = $('.nav_show_links').css('display')
            if (display == 'none') {
                $('.nav_show_links').slideDown('100')
            } else {
                $('.nav_show_links').slideUp('100')
            }
        })
    
        $('.category_btn').click(function() {
            let display = $('.categorys_container').css('display')
            if (display == 'none') {
                $('.categorys_container').slideDown('100')
                $('.category_btn').addClass('active')
            } else {
                $('.categorys_container').slideUp('100')
                $('.category_btn').removeClass('active')
            }
        })
    // Профиль и его меню
        {
            let active;
            $('#main_inf_user').click(function() {
                if (active != 'off' | active == undefined) {
                    active = 'on'
                    $('#main_inf_user').addClass('profile_active_menu')
                    $('.profile_main_content').css('display', 'inline-block')
                    $('.profile_about_me').css('display', 'none')
                    $('.profile_posts').css('display', 'none')
                    $('#posts_user').removeClass('profile_active_menu')
                    $('#about_user').removeClass('profile_active_menu')
                } else if (active == 'on') {
                    active = 'ref'
                    $('#main_inf_user').removeClass('profile_active_menu')
                }
            })
    
            $('#about_user').click(function() {
                if (active != 'off' | active == undefined) {
                    active = 'on'
                    $('#about_user').addClass('profile_active_menu')
                    $('.profile_about_me').css('display', 'inline-block')
                    $('.profile_main_content').css('display', 'none')
                    $('.profile_posts').css('display', 'none')
                    $('#posts_user').removeClass('profile_active_menu')
                    $('#main_inf_user').removeClass('profile_active_menu')
                } else if (active == 'on') {
                    active = 'ref'
                    $('#about_user').removeClass('profile_active_menu')
                }
            })
    
            $('#posts_user').click(function() {
                if (active != 'off' | active == undefined) {
                    active = 'on'
                    $('#posts_user').addClass('profile_active_menu')
                    $('.profile_posts').css('display', 'inline-block')
                    $('.profile_about_me').css('display', 'none')
                    $('.profile_main_content').css('display', 'none')
                    $('#about_user').removeClass('profile_active_menu')
                    $('#main_inf_user').removeClass('profile_active_menu')
                } else if (active == 'on') {
                    active = 'ref'
                    $('#posts_user').removeClass('profile_active_menu')
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

> подключение в шаблоне Django

```html
    <script src="{% static 'jquery-3.6.0.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'jquery.js' %}"></script>
```

а так же стили

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style_standart.css' %}">
```

> расположение статических файлов
> [они находятся в корневой папке проекта, в моём случае это /blog/static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXesX.png)

если нужно будет больше информации по поводу всего я с заинтересованностью отредактирую пост или отвечу в комментарии, действительно не понимаю из за чего это может быть и до конца не знаю какую именно информацию*, в плане кода,* написать в посте, заранее спасибо.

Comment: из-за установки свойств через js и ломаются ваши стили. просто замените установку свойств на установку классов.

Comment: @ZaArs спасибо за ответ, мне действительно помогла замена на установку классов.